`wmctrl -d` fails immediatly after login? (Gnome, Wayland)
I'm using wmctrl -d in my scripts, to open vim servers specific to each desktop.
I noticed that it fails:
> wmctrl -d
Cannot get current desktop properties. (_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP or _WIN_WORKSPACE property)

if I run it immediately after login, without having switched desktop yet. This happens in GNOME with dynamic desktops and Wayland. This seems a bit strange; I really have one desktop, which is the 0 one; if I switch desktop and come back, then it works ok:
> wmctrl -d                                              
0  * DG: 4480x1440  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,32 4480x1408  Workspace 1
1  - DG: 4480x1440  VP: N/A  WA: 0,32 4480x1408  Workspace 2

I can easily workaround it by checking the exit status, but it seems a bit strange: is it expected behavior?
My system is an up-to-date Manjaro stable, with Gnome (gnome-shell 46) and Wayland.
